# Custom Progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in creating the custom components. I am creating a Custom Progress bar by extending the **ProgressBar**. But getting this exception.

```
07-07 17:38:00.700: D/AndroidRuntime(3513): Shutting down VM
07-07 17:38:00.700: W/dalvikvm(3513): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.customprogress.TextProgressBar
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:503)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at com.customprogress.TextProgressBar.<init>(TextProgressBar.java:22)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at com.customprogress.Progress$Click.onClick(Progress.java:27)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: TextProgressBar(Context,AttributeSet)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:660)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:477)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:475)
07-07 17:38:00.720: E/AndroidRuntime(3513):     ... 20 more
```

My code for creating this is here.. TextProgressBar.class

```
public class TextProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
    Activity activity;


    public TextProgressBar(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.activity.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress);
    }
```

And I am calling this class from my Progress.java Activity

```
public class Progress extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button buttonClick;
    TextProgressBar textProgressBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new Click());
    }

    class Click implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textProgressBar = new TextProgressBar(Progress.this);
        }

    }
}
```

The xml for custom_progress is here..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.customprogress.TextProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWithText"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me out if anybody know the solution of this..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: @SpK Can you plz elaborate yourself.How do i use LayoutInflator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a second constructor.

```
public TextProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); 

}
```

See if that helps:

Comment: How do i call this AttributeSet from my Activity?

Comment: I don't think you need to call it.  You just need to have it.

Comment: @nick no need to call this constructor from your activity. Just add this constructor to your custom class and run. This constructor will be used when loading the component via layout XML files.

Comment: @sunil  yes, its working. Your answer is accepted by me. thanks. But can you please tell me how this parameterised constructor is called automatically??

Comment: @nick Thanks. You can take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: Basically that constructor allows the layout editor to create and edit an instance of your view.